# Single video not picking up on a Youtube API Title Search

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using Youtubes PHP API to get videos by title and list them on a page based on the current date. Right now one video is not showing and I cannot figure out how to debug the issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F94TV1yZ9NA

I've tried searching the channel specifically using Search: list with vague keywords in the title and the whole title but it won't pick it up.

I thought perhaps it could be a setting for the uploaded video but it seems identical to the others. Anyone ever have an issue similar to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which piece of data are you looking for?

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=F94TV1yZ9NA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Returns both the `title` and `publishedAt` date

```
{
   "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
   "etag": "\"jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/KQPGXJ3y5hdArWxw_-IKv1yQJV0\"",
   "pageInfo": {
   "totalResults": 1,
   "resultsPerPage": 1
},
 "items": [
{


 "kind": "youtube#video",
 "etag": "\"jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/5z-phmMy-V7_yf9pGOHrr3cYshs\"",
 "id": "F94TV1yZ9NA",
 "snippet": {
  "publishedAt": "2015-09-13T22:40:04.000Z",
  "channelId": "UCkhBqbxs8CbO-vYxKROF73g",
  "title": "CDP 2015 September 12 R11",
  "description": "Located at 21 Exhibition Drive in Charlottetown, RED SHORES Racetrack & Casino at Charlottetown Driving Park combines the excitement of live harness & simulcast racing, slots, poker, food and fun in one 'RED HOT' bundle of entertainment - all done Island style!\n\nLocated at 55 Greenwood Drive in Summerside, RED SHORES at Summerside Raceway also offers a RED HOT entertainment package, featuring live & simulcast racing, a gaming floor with 40 slots and live Texas Hold'em Poker tables, plus, casual food & drink in the WEST-END Bar & Grill\n\nRedshores.ca",
  "thumbnails": {
```

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet&id=F94TV1yZ9NA&_h=2&

**EDIT:**

If you do a search for the first 20 videos published after 1st September 2015:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCkhBqbxs8CbO-vYxKROF73g&maxResults=20&order=date&publishedAfter=2015-09-01T00%3A00%3A00.000Z&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

the `videoID` you mentioned (F94TV1yZ9NA) is returned

[Try it](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it)